# I am learning Android studio and doing a rectangle calculator, my kotlin has 19 errors and cannot figure it out

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, calculator

I am learning Android studio and doing a rectangle calculator. My Kotlin has 19 errors, and I cannot figure it out. I keep getting unresolved errors for btn, functions that cannot be called, and expecting an element. I am trying to do a calculator that takes height and width and then calculates area and perimeter. Just need guidance on what I am doing wrong and not looking for someone to give me new code.

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.calculator

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.icu.text.DecimalFormat
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btn_calculate.setOnClickListener {
            calculate()
            btn_calculate.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
        }
        btn_reset.setOnClickListener {
            reset()
        }
    }
    private fun calculate() {
        val formatter = DecimalFormat("#.##")
        val editNum1 = (EditText) editNum1.text.toString()
        val editNum2 = (EditText) editNum2.text.toString()

        val Area = DecimalFormat(editNum1.toDouble() * editNum2.toDouble())
        val Perimeter = DecimalFormat(2* ( (editNum1.toDouble()) + (editNum2.toDouble()))
    }}
```

Comment: Can you show the error to us

Comment: Post the stack trace or the error log you are getting.

Comment: Seems like you forgot to define `btn_calculate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the views from your XML file directly in your activity you should use Kotlin Android Extension. But this plugin is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration). You should migrate to [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

Comment: Kotlin extensions is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration). Please [edit] your answer to remove it.

Comment: sorry for sounding dumb but I just started Android studio this week and it is an online course and the text book used is from 2015. So Kotlin extension in the import library is no longer used and I have to do view-binding?

Comment: @Jensy yeah the synthetic binding stuff was a bit "magical" and it's been deprecated for a long time - the good news is View Binding works almost exactly the same way, you just have to explicitly create a binding object and reference all your views on that. So ``binding.btnCalculate`` instead of just saying ``btn_calculate`` like it's a variable that exists (it doesn't, that's where the "magical" part comes in!) Honestly once you get the idea it's no trouble, almost exactly the same

Comment: Thank you will try the steps